# Ada: Null exclusion in arrays holding pointers

Tags: ada

I was trying to use null excluded arrays holding access types in Ada.
Example:

```
type Integer_Access is access all Integer;
type MyArr is array (1 .. 2) of not null Integer_Access;
```

My compiler keeps warning me that a Costraint_Error may be thrown at runtime
(only by declaring this type, without instantiation).
Is declaring such an array illegal (or bad practice)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access types are initialized to null (see the [ARM](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-10.html) and the [rational](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-2-6.html)).
When declaring a variable of this type, it would be initialized with null values which is forbidden by the type itself.

On my side, I get the message:

```
access_array.adb:6:04: warning: (Ada 2005) null-excluding objects must be initialized
access_array.adb:6:04: warning: "Constraint_Error" will be raised at run time
```

From my point of view, the only way to deal with this is to provide some kind of constructor.

Comment: It compiles fine on GNAT Community 2021 (20210519-103) on Windows

Comment: @AnhVo: I had to declare an uninitialized variable of type `MyArr` to see the warnings.

Comment: @trashgod: That is a good thing preventing for doing some thing like this. Thus, initialization is required when declaring an object of MyArr. For example, The_Arr : MyArr := (others => new Integer);

Comment: Thanks Frederic for the link to the rational, I discovered the Default_Component_Value aspect (even if it doesn't work in this case because we're dealing with access types).

Comment: @AnhVo You're right, a simple Initialization is easier :)